# Is there any Primary Key (or) Unique Key is present in Active Directory?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, ldap

I am running the below command from PowerShell:

```
Get-ADUser -Server ad.com -Filter '*' -Properties '*' Export-Csv 'C:\Users\myFolder\file.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter '|'
```

Just trying to identify the Attribute which I can use as a 'Primary Key' such as EmployeeID or EmployeeNumber.
AD Attributes List: [link]
Does AD provide a Primary Key?

Comment: Can you describe your use case? There are several fields to choose from.

Comment: I am trying to identify a 'primary key' & 'modified timestamp' which I can use to update a Hive table every day whilst pulling of all the records from AD using Get-ADUser -Server ad.com -Filter '*' -Properties '*'.
The AD output provides the following attribute "modifyTimeStamp" which I can use for Data column, but I am unable to find the best Primary key that I can use.

Answer (score 9):

If you need a unique value in user and group entries you can look at attribute [objectSID](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/ADSchema/a-objectsid). The LDAP string representation is an *OctetString* but you can find code to convert this into a ASCII-clean so-called SDDL representation.

Note that SIDs contain the domain's SID as prefix. So in case the domain gets migrated new SIDs are generated and old SIDs are placed in attribute [sIDHistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/ADSchema/a-sidhistory) until cleaned up by the AD admins.

However if you're looking for a primary key to sync data with an external data source I'd create the unique value in this external data source and place it in [employeeID](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/ADSchema/a-employeeid) or [employeeNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/ADSchema/a-employeenumber).

While many other attributes have to be unique some are not really stable or local and thus not suitable e.g. for syncing data:

[objectGUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/ADSchema/a-objectGUID) is globally unique because it is a UUID (see [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122)) encoded as *OctetString*. But IIRC it is not stable across replicas.

*samAccountName* and *userPrincipalName* are often derived from person names. The entry's RDN in AD is also based on *cn* which most times contains the person's name. Values derived from person's name will likely be changed after marriage/divorce etc.

=>

- The best attribute for syncing is a self-generated ID (e.g. an UUID).
- The 2nd best attribute is *objectSID* used in combination with *sIDHistory* for locating the entry. Make sure to sync back current value of *objectSID* to your data source.

Comment: So, Michael, you're saying that objectGUID is the best attribute to consider as Unique Key, as per my below trying:

I am trying to identify a 'primary key' & 'modified timestamp' which I can use to update a Hive table every day whilst pulling of all the records from AD using Get-ADUser -Server ad.com -Filter '' -Properties ''. The AD output provides the following attribute "modifyTimeStamp" which I can use for Data column, but I am unable to find the best Primary key that I can use.

Comment: No. I said _objectSID_ is the best attribute for syncing along with looking at _sIDHistory_ to even survive domain migrations.

Answer (score 8):

It is [pretty well documented](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2009/07/10/understanding-unique-attributes-in-active-directory/) if you look.

Distinguished name is the primary key. As a hierarchical database, the full path to the object with the canonical name must be unique in the forest.

[samAccountName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-samaccountname) and [userPrincipalName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-userprincipalname) must also be unique across security principals in a domain.

objectSID is unique across the domain.

objectGUID is globally unique.

That said, I have seen oddball situations where the user principal name or samAccountName are duplicated, but that causes problems because the system assumes they must be unique.

EmployeeNumber is a user specified property. It's intended to be populated with the id from your user database or HR database to keep demographic and organizational data up to date.  The attribute itself has no constraints.

Comment: There are some caveats with all these unique attributes. I've added more text to my answer discussing this. Feedback welcome.

Comment: Note that `userPrincipalName` is unique across a whole AD forest too (if you have multiple domains in your forest).

Comment: Yes, Gabriel, I've Multiple Domains and userPrincipalName would be unique for all of them?

Comment: So Bacon, you're saying that ObjectGUID is best to use as a Primary key?

Comment: @Pavan_Obj It depends. The only advantage `objectGuid` gives you is that it can never change, but do you care? `userPrincipalName` is guaranteed unique and is human readable, but can be changed (like if the person changes their name).